# How to write a bash script to generate a file named inputFile with comma separated values with index and a random number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Can someone help on how to write an bash script to generate a file named inputFile whose content looks like:

```
0, 334

1, 933

2, 34123

3, 123
```

These are comma separated values with index and a random number.

> Running the script without any arguments, should generate the file inputFile with 10 such entries in current directory.

> You should be able to extend this script to generate any number of entries, for example 100000 entries.

I tried below script, But its not as expectation could someone help to fix this as I am new to scripting?

```
RANDOM=$$
num=0

while [[ ${num} -le $1 ]]
do
    echo $num $RANDOM
    (( num = num +1 ))
done
```

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: Say bash script csv.sh, It should generate a file named inputFile whose content looks like.
0, 334

1, 933

2, 34123

3, 123

4, 12345

5, 6783

Running the script without any arguments, should generate the file inputFile with 10 such entries in current directory also we should be able to extend this script to generate any number of entries,
for example 100000 entries. This is requirement !

Comment: Please update/edit your question to reflect such requirement, not here in the comment section, so others can read everything also.

Comment: I have updated the clear requirement in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a C-style `for` loop in `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=10
for ((i=0; i<n; ++i)); do
    echo "$i,$RANDOM"
done > inputFile
```

Modify the `n=10` as needed.
Alternatively, using a `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=10
i=0
while ((i<n)); do
    echo "$((i++)),$RANDOM"
done > inputFile
```